# Get user information in Windows Phone 8 app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm making a game which have a hightscore table (on my server), now I need to get a unique information of the player (email, MS accout name, Live ID...) or any other way to define people to add to the highscore, so is there anyway to get that information ?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the **ANID2**. It is an identifier that is unique to the Windows Live ID of the user and the publisher ID of the app.

```
string anid2 = (string)Microsoft.Phone.Info.UserExtendedProperties.GetValue("ANID2");
```

To use this Api you have to add the "ID_CAP_IDENTITY_USER" capability in the app manifest. You may also find [this blogpost](http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2013/03/11/migrating-anids-to-windows-phone-8/) helpful.